# Selecting CASE with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I am performing a query where there is a `GROUP BY` and the selected columns uses a `CASE`.

This is the important part of my huge query:

```sql
SELECT users.id
     , CASE
       WHEN MAX(flagged)
       THEN "has a flagged comment"
       END
  FROM users
  JOIN comments
    ON comments.user_id = users.id
 GROUP BY users.id
```

My understanding is that when using `GROUP BY`, every selected column must either be in the `GROUP BY` clause or it must be an aggregating function.

Strictly speaking, this `CASE` is not an aggregating function. But practically speaking, it is equivalent to a different syntax that is an aggregating function:

```sql
, MAX(CASE WHEN flagged THEN "has a flagged comment" END)
```

Does this top syntax produce undefined behavior?

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What do you mean with "undefined behavior" ? The both syntax are valid. The first one will first find the max flagged then return "has a flagged comment" if this max is true (else NULL). The second will replace flagged with "has a flagged comment" if true else with NULL) and then  return the max between "has a flagged comment" and NULL (which result, I think could be different depending on some parameters because you may have a rule "anything not NULL"  is higher than NULL or a rule "NULL" is higher than "anything not NULL")

Comment: While the `CASE` is not an aggregate function, the `MAX` inside it is. Your top syntax works with MySQL.